# Is it true that if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are isomorphic cyclic subgroups of $G$, then $G/H_1\cong G/H_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have a question: it is true that if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are cyclic groups that are isomorphic, then $G/H_1$ is isomorphic to $G/H_2$? I know that if I remove the condition "cyclic groups", the given statement is false and there are numerous counterexamples that disprove it, but I don't know if my statement is true and I don't how to create a counterexample or to prove it. If it is true, can you give me a hint about how this can be proven?

For example, I just have shown that $Z_{12}/ \langle 2 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $Z_{12}/Z_6$ which is isomorphic to $Z_3$ (since both $\langle 2 \rangle$ and $Z_6$ are isomorphic). How this can be generalized?

Comment: You haven't specified whether $G$ is abelian or whether your subgroups are normal or not, so it's ambiguous what you mean by "isomorphic" in your question. If $G$ is nonabelian the natural reading would be "isomorphic as $G$-sets," but it sounds like you intend $G$ to be abelian and to ask for an isomorphism of abelian groups.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Many people working in group theory (including myself) only write $G/N$ when $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. And the fact that reference is made to isomorphisms between two quotients strongly suggests that this convention is eing used here.

Comment: I agree with Derek. In this particular case though, I think the OP has simply neglected to mention that $H_1$, $H_2$ are assumed to be normal subgroups of the group.

Comment: @Derek: really? Then how do you refer to the transitive $G$-set with stabilizer $H$?

Comment: I don't have a specific notation for that. But in any case that would (mildly) conflict with its meaning as a quotient group, because a group is not the same thing as a $G$-set.

Answer (score 7):

No, that's not true. Take $G = C_2 \times C_4$ and note that since $G$ is abelian, every subgroup of $G$ is normal in $G$. Let $H = C_2$ be the first direct factor of $G$ and $K$ be the unique subgroup of order $2$ of $C_4$. Obviously, $H \cong K$ since both have order $2$, but $G/H \cong C_4$ while $G/K \cong C_2 \times C_2$.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try cyclic subgroups of the additive group of integers $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: But what about integers mod n? I edited my question and I found very interesting that observation about the isomorphism about quotient groups.

Answer (score 0):

$m\mathbb Z\cong n\mathbb Z\cong Z$ for $m\neq n$, but $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\not\cong\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.